# Express, NodeJS) How do I modify response before piping it to client?

Tags: node.js, api, express, request

Hi I am using code below to communicate with Google Place API and sending back relevant data to client.

```
app.get('/city',(req,res)=>{
const cityname = req.query.name;
console.log(apiKey);
request({
  uri:'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json',
  qs:{
    query:"point of interest in"+cityname,
    key:apiKey
  }
}).pipe(res);
});
```

When I check in my browser, my react gets such data from server.

```
html_attributions: Array(0), next_page_token: some token number, results: Array(20), status: 'OK'}
html_attributions: []
next_page_token: some token number
results: (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
status: "OK"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

So my client is getting too much unnecessary data. So, before piping data, I would like to remove all unnecessary data from the res and send only necessary data to client.

I tried this way, but not sure is it right way to go

```
app.get('/city',(req,res)=>{
const cityname = req.query.name;
console.log(apiKey);
let objectToClient;
request({
  uri:'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json',
  qs:{
    query:"point of interest in"+cityname,
    key:apiKey
  }
},()=>{
  objectToClient = modified res 
}).pipe(objectToClient);
});
```

Is it right? Or is there any other way?

Comment: You need some sort of streaming JSON filter like [`stream-json`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json) or [`bfj`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bfj). Or, if the results aren't _that_ large, don't use streaming and just retrieve the result, modify it, then send it to the client.

Comment: @robertklep do you mean I can use res.send() in anonymous function I made instead of doing pipe? but is it good practice?

Comment: Using `pipe()` is certainly more efficient in terms of memory use, but it's not trivial to modify streaming data. So like I said, if the results you get from Google aren't _that_ large, you might as well read them into memory first. If will make modifying them a lot easier.